# Send Push Notification or Passbook Pass without an installed app via iBeacon

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ibeacon

Is it possible to notify a user or push a Passbook Pass to a user when he is nearby a certain location (for example with iBeacon).

I thought I read somewhere that iBeacon was able to send a message with a link to the app when somebody was nearby an iBeacon without having the app installed that is linked to that certain iBeacon. I can't seem to find this inside Apple's documentation or anywhere else around the web.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks!

Brecht

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad news but you can't send data trought ibeacons without an app.

Passbook works with ibeacon natively but only for the relevency of the pass. 
(relevency of a pass makes it apear on the lock screen)

For passbook there are 3 ways to make a pass relevent (but the pass needs to be added to the phone before)

-with a relevent date 
-with geo aware abilities (up to 10 locations) 
-with ibeacon

Best regards

Malo